# How to implement Q-learning with a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I have created a neural network with 2 inputs nodes, 4 hidden nodes and 3 output nodes. The initial weights are random between -1 to 1. I used backpropagation method to update the network with TD error. However, the performance is not good.

I want to know, where the problem might be?
1. Is a bias node necessary?
2. Are eligibility traces necessary?

If anyone can provide me any sample code, I'm very grateful.

Comment: I'd say 4 hidden nodes is way to little for 3 output nodes, I suggest an absolute minimum of 10. It obviously depends on how many / complex features you want to learn. I'm pretty sure a bias node should only be omitted by exception.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should include the bias nodes, and yes you should use eligibility traces. The bias nodes just give one additional tunable parameter. Think of the neural network as a "function approximator" as described in Sutton and Barto's book ([free online](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html)). If the neural network has parameters theta (a vector containing all of the weights in the network), then the Sarsa update is just (using LaTeX notation):

\delta_t = r_t + \gamma*Q(s_{t+1},a_{t+1},\theta_t) - Q(s_t,a_t, \theta_t)

\theta_{t+1} = \theta_t + \alpha*\delta_t*\frac{\partial Q(s,a,\theta)}{\partial \theta}

This is for any function approximator Q(s,a,\theta), which estimates Q(s,a) by tuning its parameters, \theta.

However, I must ask why you're doing this. If you're just trying to get Q learning working really well, then you should use the Fourier Basis instead of a neural network:

http://all.cs.umass.edu/pubs/2011/konidaris_o_t_11.pdf

If you really want to use a neural network for RL, then you should use a natural actor-critic (NAC). NACs follow something called the "natural gradient," which was developed by Amari specifically to speed up learning using neural networks, and it makes a *huge* difference.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information.  What is the problem domain.  What are the inputs?  What are the outputs?

RL can take a very long time to train and, depending on how you're training, can go from good to great to good to not-so-good during training.  Therefore, you should plot the performance of your agent during learning, not just the end result.

You always should use bias nodes.  Eligibility traces?  Probably not.